# Как из строки с наименованием цвета (например clGold) получить RGB-составляющие цвета

Tags: pascalabc.net, color

Если мою просьбу изложить коротко, без предисловия, то нужно из строки с наименованием цвета (например clGold) получить RGB-составляющие цвета.

А если не кратко, то...

Pascal ABC.NET

В справке (Стандартные модули\Модуль GraphABC) есть таблица "Цветовые константы".

Цветовые константы представлены в виде некоего "наименования цвета".
Например, у цвета "золотой" имя "clGold".

Эти цветовые константы были скопированы из справки и вставлены в Word в таблицу.
То есть, имеется ячейка таблицы в Word-е, в которой хранится значение (наименование) цвета.
Захотел залить ячейку цветом, наименование которого в ячейке хранится.

Написал небольшую программу, в которую (в переменную "с") ввожу скопированное из ячейки Word-а значение.
Программа получает из наименования Цвета  его RGB-значения и записывает это в текстовый файл.
Далее в модуле GraphABC рисуется небольшой прямоугольник и заливается Цветом.

В Word-е на ленте разместил кнопку, к которой привязал маленькую программу, написанную на
VBA. Программка читает из текстового файла строку с RGB-значением Цвета, получает из строки RGB-значения Цвета. И заливает ячейку Цветом.

Так все работает.

Вот программа:

```
##
uses System.Windows.Forms, GraphABC;


SetWindowSize(250, 120);
SetWindowCaption('цвета и r g b - значения');

//var c := Clipboard.GetText;       // переменная - цвет !!! получаем из буфера обмена
{Это не работает. Компилятор ругается "Нельзя преобразовать тип string к 
 System.Drawing.Color"}

//var cl := c.ToColor;
var c: color := clGold;

var r := GetRed(c);     // Возвращает красную составляющую цвета
var g := GetGreen(c);   // Возвращает зеленую составляющую цвета
var b := GetBlue(c);    // Возвращает синюю составляющую цвета
println(c);                   // печать названия цвета
var color: string := r.ToString + ', ' + g.ToString + ', ' + b.ToString;
WriteAllText('d:\PABCWork.NET\color.txt', color); 

print(r, g, b);               // печать r g b - значения цвета
setpenwidth(1);               // установили толщину пера = 1
setpencolor(clGray);          // установили цвет пера

moveTo(50, 50);       // перо в точку 50, 50
lineTo(200, 50);      // линия до точки 200, 50
lineto(200, 100);     // линия до точки 200, 100
lineto(50, 100);      // линия до точки 50, 100
lineto(50, 50);       // линия до точки 50, 50      
floodfill(75, 75, c); // от точки 75, 75 заливаем цветом
```

===
Захотел исключить из цепочки действий (копирование из ячейки Word-а значения Цвета → вставка этого значения в программу) второе звено цепочки - вставку. Пусть программа получает строку со значением цвета из буфера обмена.
Получать-то она получает, но дальше при попытке получить из строки значение  GetRed(c) начинает ругаться "Нельзя преобразовать тип string к System.Drawing.Color"

Может быть кто-то поможет справиться с этим местом:

```
##
uses System.Windows.Forms, GraphABC;


SetWindowSize(250, 120);
SetWindowCaption('цвета и r g b - значения');

var c := Clipboard.GetText;       // переменная - цвет !!! получаем из буфера обмена
{Это не работает. Компилятор ругается "Нельзя преобразовать тип string к 
 System.Drawing.Color"}

//var cl := c.ToColor;
//var c: color := clGold;

var r := GetRed(c);     // Возвращает красную составляющую цвета
var g := GetGreen(c);   // Возвращает зеленую составляющую цвета
var b := GetBlue(c);    // Возвращает синюю составляющую цвета
println(c);                   // печать названия цвета
var color: string := r.ToString + ', ' + g.ToString + ', ' + b.ToString;
WriteAllText('d:\PABCWork.NET\color.txt', color);
```

Comment: А если не секрет, зачем вам цвет из буфера обмена? Вообще говоря это не логично. Весьма вероятно, что в буфере будет не цвет. Кучу проверок проходить.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел (подсказали) решение
Цвет получить из названия можно так:

```
var c := system.Drawing.Color.FromName(Clipboard.GetText)

##
uses System.Windows.Forms, GraphABC;


SetWindowSize(450, 120);
SetWindowCaption('цвета и r g b - значения');
// clGold
var c := system.Drawing.Color.FromName(Clipboard.GetText);// переменная 
- цвет !!! получаем из буфера обмена
print('c ', c, '**'); println(c.GetType().FullName);


var r := GetRed(c);     // Возвращает красную составляющую цвета
var g := GetGreen(c);   // Возвращает зеленую составляющую цвета
var b := GetBlue(c);    // Возвращает синюю составляющую цвета
                        // печать названия цвета
var color: string := r.ToString + ', ' + g.ToString + ', ' + b.ToString;
WriteAllText('d:\PABCWork.NET\color.txt', color); 

print(r, g, b);               // печать r g b - значения цвета
setpenwidth(1);               // установили толщину пера = 1
setpencolor(clGray);          // установили цвет пера

moveTo(50, 50);       // перо в точку 50, 50
lineTo(200, 50);      // линия до точки 200, 50
lineto(200, 100);     // линия до точки 200, 100
lineto(50, 100);      // линия до точки 50, 100
lineto(50, 50);       // линия до точки 50, 50      
floodfill(75, 75, c); // от точки 75, 75 заливаем цветом
```

Answer (score 0):

#### В VBA тоже есть цветовые константы

PascalABC.Net: clGold

VBA: rgbGold

Хотя за полное их соответствие не ручаюсь

#### Поменять стандартную палитру

Возможно вам просто не нравятся стандартные цвета заливки в приложениях MSOffice. Вот [ссылочка на справку](https://itigic.com/ru/how-to-change-and-customize-the-word-color-palette/) как поменять палитру.

Кстати для формирования собственной палитры/цветовой темы/схемы советую инструмент от GitHub [Prizm](https://primer.style/prism/), он построен на цветовой схеме [HSLuv](https://www.hsluv.org/) (так для общего развития)

#### Перегонка цветов все же нужна

Нужна, то нужна, но как минимум не оптимально гонять еще одну программу кроме Word, каждый раз как понадобится цвет. Тем более, что у вас есть полный список названий цветов. Проще взять все данные цветов разом и сделать из них цветовые константы в VBA

Конвертирование из PascalABC.Net

```pascal
uses System.Drawing;
uses GraphABC;
uses System.Text;
uses System.Windows.Forms;

begin
    // начальнный ввод как список строк, но можно считывать из файла или как-то по другому.
    var names := new List<string>(Arr('clGold', 'clGreen', 'clBlack'));
    Println(names);
    
    var sb := new StringBuilder();
    
    foreach var name in names do
    begin
        var c := Color.FromName(name.Substring(2)); // обрезается начало имени, префикс "cl"
        //в VBA  и не только значение цвета хранится в виде лонгинт. 
        var long_val := GetBlue(c) * 65536 + GetGreen(c) * 256 + GetRed(c); 
        //К сожалению, константе нельзя присвоить вычисляэмую функцию
        sb.AppendFormat('Public Const {0} = {1} '' RGB({2}, {3}, {4})' + END_OF_LINE_SYMBOL, 
            name, long_val, GetRed(c), GetGreen(c), GetBlue(c));
    end;
    
    WriteAllText('MyColorCollection.bas', sb.ToString); 
end.
```

На выходе получаем файл со списком констант, который можно сразу импортировать в VBA (Редактор VBA: Файл - Импортировать файл)

У меня получился такой файл для импорта

```
Public Const clGold = 55295 ' RGB(255, 215, 0)
Public Const clGreen = 32768 ' RGB(0, 128, 0)
Public Const clBlack = 0 ' RGB(0, 0, 0)
```